# Does requiring POST plus custom Content-Type prevent CSRF?

Tags: ajax, wcf, content-type, csrf

My team is building a site that uses AJAX calls to WCF services for all state changes.  Those services only accept a request if its method is POST and its Content-Type is 'application/json'.  Assuming that our site has no XSS vulnerabilities, is this sufficient protection against CSRF for our WCF services?  Is it possible for an attacker to create a cross-site POST with a custom Content-Type header?

[EDIT]
Obviously there are several ways for a malicious third party site to construct an HTTP POST request to my site.  As far as I am aware, however, none of these methods allow for changing the Content-Type header.  XHR and Flash both let you set headers, but have strict cross-site restrictions.

Answer (score 1):

Probably, but why not go ahead and check the HTTP Referrer header? Then you will know for sure.